# Wordpress Multisite one network site pages redirecting to parent site after changing URL

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-routing

I have a multisite with about 30 network sites on it. I had one site that I previously had on its own url, for example instead of:

`https://sites.mymultisites.com/network-site`

it was on

`https://network-site.com`

However we needed to take that website down, so I updated the URL for the corresponding `wp_8_options` so that `siteurl` and `home` both pointed to `https://sites.mymultisites.com/network-site` again (away from the unique domain and back to our multisite as a subfolder site).

I've done this in the past for other network sites and it worked fine, but for some reason on this particular site all the pages now redirect to the "default" network site (the one referred to by the default wp_options table as opposed to a numbered one).

I made sure that any routing information in apache for that `https://network-site.com` domain was removed, although that shouldn't be effecting it in any way since the `siteurl` and `home` wp_options have been changed away from that domain anyway. I've doublechecked the `.htaccess`, but I never edited that to begin with and it is the default wordpress multisite htaccess content.

I checked the `wp_8_posts` table to make sure that the correct posts still existed and they do! I think it's just a routing issue but i have no idea how to fix it, does anyone know what else I can do to remedy this?

Let me know if I'm missing any info that I can add to the post. Thanks!

.htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]




# END WordPress
```

Editing to add:
All the other sites in the network are working fine and point to the correct network site's content, only this one is giving me trouble. Could I have missed something when I was updating it? Usually I only ever update `siteurl` and `home`

Comment: Check the `wp_blogs` table, all sites with their base domain and path are also contained in that table.

Comment: @CBroe That was exactly it, thanks so much!